# References Issue

Tags: job-offer, new-job, tech-industry

I'm interviewing with a company as a new graduate, and I have been asked for professional references.

I had 3 internships and can get references from 2 of them. Last internship ( and the most relevant one) made me a full time offer that I politely declined because it was too low. Unfortunately it offended the manager who was expecting that I would join the company.

Now I'm not sure if it is still okay to list him as my reference, or to even ask for a reference. What is the best action to take in this situation?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this guy will stitch you up?

Comment: I honestly feel even weird to ask after declining his offer. He seemed to be pissed (I told him I got another offer), but besides that he was happy with my work. So not sure

Answer (score 2):

**As alternatives to your previous manager, consider the following for references:**

**1. Another manager at the same company.** Even if you only occasionally worked together, another manager would probably be happy to be a reference for you.

**2. A senior leader at the same company.** Your boss's boss, or even higher up would be a great reference. If there is someone who was familiar with what you were working on, it wouldn't hurt to ask.

**3. Professors or staff from school.** For entry level jobs, professors can be fine professional references, especially if you did something like assist with research, TA a class, or were involved in student government.

It's also okay to submit multiple references from the same company.

Best of luck with the interview!

Comment: Thank you! I will reach out to other senior employees!

Comment: Or, if it's just to confirm your work history (rather than write you a review) somebody from HR in that company would do.